# position of "because"

Tags: word-usage

In one of my posts ([How do I say "a bottle of water" in the colloquial way?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/241205/109190)), a nice contributor ask me

> Why would you think this is not everyday English? Why are you asking about this phrase and not another one?

I answered

> **Because** when I searched "bottles of water" I got lots of water bottles.

By those words, I was trying to describe and emphasize a fact, that is, most of the results for that searching is about bottles rather than water.

I guess my answer is grammatical though, I am not sure whether it is idiomatic. I am also not sure I put the right order to emphasize that fact. Is the following version better?

> **Because** I got lots of water bottles when I searched "bottles of water".

Are there other expressions more appropriate? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say the first version is better because it emphasises the search term you were using.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions sound natural and I wouldn't flinch hearing either version from a native English speaker - which would explain why that contributor was confused at the question.

The first version certainly sounds more natural and smoother to me but I'm trying to pinpoint exactly why; I'm unsure if it sounds better for a grammatical reason or if it's simply a smoother train of thought to follow. It helps that it provides the necessary context upfront, at the very least.